# Custom order of display of completions - monaco

Tags: monaco-editor

I am referring to the [completion-provider-example](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-completion-provider-example) for monaco.

I noticed that the completions are defined in this order: `lodash, express, mkdirp` but the suggestions in the editor are listed alphabetically.

I would like to customize this behaviour. Is this possible? I have looked at this [pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/22884/files), but can't get it wired up.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the example that you link to, simply add the `sortText` key to each completion item. This value is used for determining the order of the items in the completion box.

Modification to linked example:

```
return [
    {
        label: '"lodash"',
        kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Function,
        documentation: "The Lodash library exported as Node.js modules.",
        insertText: '"lodash": "*"',
        sortText: 'a'
    },
    {
        label: '"express"',
        kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Function,
        documentation: "Fast, unopinionated, minimalist web framework",
        insertText: '"express": "*"',
        sortText: 'b'
    },
    {
        label: '"mkdirp"',
        kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Function,
        documentation: "Recursively mkdir, like <code>mkdir -p</code>",
        insertText: '"mkdirp": "*"',
        sortText: 'c'
    }
];
```

The sortText values 'a', 'b', 'c' now determine the order of the suggestions.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of `sortText`, don't know if it was added later, but exactly what I was after.